# how to bazel build a C++ windows executable w/o it needing vcruntime DLLs?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, bazel

I want to know how to write a cc_binary() BUILD rule that produces a standalone executable. It's a console application. My current BUILD rule is making that exe to depend on both vcruntime140.dll and vcruntime140_1.dll

My current dev env is Bazel and Windows 8 with the latest MSVC community version, but I also wanted to write this BUILD rule in a way that I could run it in Linux too. (so I guess I can't just stuff non-portable flags like `/MT` there)

Comment: Statically link the MSVC runtime.Under project options, look under C/C++ and then Code Generation and then Runtime Library. Choose Multi Threaded for release mode and Multi Threaded debug for debug mode. The defaults are to use the dynamic versions.

Comment: I am using Bazel CLI. MSVC is just the compiler. I want to know how to do this via BUILD rules.

Answer (score 1):

I builded Tensorflow with bazel and did next:

1. After configuration add to .bazelrc file params:

```
build:windows --cxxopt=/MT
build:windows --host_copt=/MT
```

2. Replace `/MD` to `/MT` in all .bzl and .bzl.tpl files
3. Remove `/DEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib` param from tensorflow.dll-2.params file before linking.